# WITHIN GROUP clause how does it work in this percentile function

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT 
    sum(p0010001) AS "County Sum",
    round(avg(p0010001), 0) AS "County Average",
    percentile_cont(.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY p0010001) AS "County Median"
FROM us_counties_2010;
```

i am unable to get what is WITHIN GROUP clause is doing in this PostgreSQL aggregate function.

p0010001 is Total population of particular state and data type  integer

Comment: Since you've stated Postgres I removed the conflicting *mysql* tag

Comment: Please provide the tables structure and minimal sample data [mre]

Comment: What exactly the. problem. It looks work here: https://sqlize.online/sql/psql14/3195386c6762a4c5885842b24bb723d2/

Comment: It's normally on what you have in the `GROUP BY`. But since there's no `GROUP BY` clause, I guess it's the median of p0010001 on the whole table.

Comment: the problem is with the understanding of how is within group clause is working

Comment: Probably worth reading the docs for [Ordered-Set Aggregate Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-ORDEREDSET-TABLE) as this will provide the official explanation, but in short it is the column that you want to perform the aggregate on, but for some functions (e.g. `percentile_dist`) the sort order will impact the result, so must be specified ([Example here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=eddeb7e0ee8d1ee4a851e8ee7e082ab7)). I assume for consistency they all use the same syntax even if the sort order is not relevant.

Comment: ```group``` in ``` within group```  clause will not cluster together similar values like ```group by```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for some reason or sense here that does not exist.  The whole construct `WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ...)` is just the magic phrase that makes the percentile functions run.  I don't think you can pick it apart and understand the individual components, like you can with other analytical/window functions.  If you want to use the built-in percentiles, you need to regurgitate the incantation.  This is certainly one of the less sensible parts of the SQL language. (I don't know if Ordered-Set Aggregate Functions are part of the SQL spec, or if they are a PostgreSQL extension)

Comment: ok, i was getting confused as i was trying to make sense out of it